# Hardware instancing retrieve color from Model

Tags: c#, monogame, hlsl

Hello I'm using c# with monogame and rendering models with hardware instancing I extract a models vertices, normal, textureCoordinate and color. When I render the model using its Texture and textureCoordinate with HLSL the model looks fine. But when I render the model only by its Color it comes up all broken and wrong.

[image]

- The left model is correct this is the same 3d model but is loaded as a single 3d model without hardware instancing. This is how the colors should look I used blender to manually set these colors.
- The right model is using hardware instancing, the shape looks correct but the colors are wrong.

**This is how I initialize the custom vertex decleration:**

```
public struct VertexPositionNormalTextureColor
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Normal;
    public Vector2 TextureCoordinate;
    public Vector4 Color;

    public VertexPositionNormalTextureColor(Vector3 _Position, Vector3 _Normal, Vector2 _TextureCoordinate, Vector4 _Color)
    {
        Position = _Position;
        Normal = _Normal;
        TextureCoordinate = _TextureCoordinate;
        Color = _Color;
    }

    static public VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration { get { return MyVertexDeclaration; } }

    static readonly VertexDeclaration MyVertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(new VertexElement[]
    {
        new VertexElement( 0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0 ),
        new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0 ),
        new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 6, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0 ),
        new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 8, VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0 )
    });
}
```

**This is how I gather the models vertices, normal, textureCoordinate and color:**

```
List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
List<Vector3> normal = new List<Vector3>();
List<Vector2> texCoord = new List<Vector2>();
List<Vector4> color = new List<Vector4>();

bones = new Matrix[myModel.Bones.Count];

myModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(bones);
foreach (ModelMesh mm in myModel.Meshes)
{
    foreach (ModelMeshPart mmp in mm.MeshParts)
    {
        VertexPositionNormalTextureColor[] vertexData = new 
        VertexPositionNormalTextureColor[mmp.NumVertices];

        mmp.VertexBuffer.GetData(mmp.VertexOffset * mmp.VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration.VertexStride, 
        vertexData, 0, mmp.NumVertices, mmp.VertexBuffer.VertexDeclaration.VertexStride);
        for (int i = 0; i != vertexData.Length; i++)
        {
             vertices.Add(vertexData[i].Position);
             normal.Add(vertexData[i].Normal);
             texCoord.Add(vertexData[i].TextureCoordinate);
             color.Add(vertexData[i].Color);
        }
    }    
}
```

**This is how I set the models vertices, normal, textureCoordinate, color to the vertex buffer:**

```
jvertices = new List<VertexPositionNormalTextureColor>(vertices.Count);
for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Count(); i++)
{
    jvertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormalTextureColor(vertices[i], normal[i], texCoord[i], color[i]));
}

geometryBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, VertexPositionNormalTextureColor.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Count(), BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
geometryBuffer.SetData(jvertices.ToArray());
```

**The code for the HLSL is as below:**

```
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float3 inPositionOS : SV_Position;
    float3 NormalOS : NORMAL0;
    float2 inTexCoords : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 inColor : COLOR0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 PositionCS : SV_Position;     //clip space
    float4 PositionWS : POSITIONWS;      //world space
    float3 NormalWS : NORMAL0;
    float2 inTexCoords : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 inColor : COLOR0;
};

VertexShaderOutput InstancingVS(VertexShaderInput input, float4x4 instanceTransform : TEXCOORD2)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4x4 instance = transpose(instanceTransform);

    output.PositionWS = mul(float4(input.inPositionOS.xyz, 1.0f), instance);
    output.PositionCS = mul(output.PositionWS, ViewProjection);
    output.NormalWS = normalize(mul(input.NormalOS, (float3x3)instance));
    output.inTexCoords = input.inTexCoords;
    output.inColor = input.inColor;

    return output;
}

float4 InstancingPS(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    float4 color = input.inColor;

    if (color.a < 0.75f) { clip(-1); return color; }
    else color.a = 1;

    return color;
}
```

If anyone notices any issue that might be the reason why Color wont work on HLSL but a texture works perfectly fine.

**Edit:**

I changed the order of the variables in the struct setting the vertex declaration. It turns out it changed the result I looked into what mmp.VertexBuffer.GetData() actually had stored from the model and for some reason it doesn't have Color.

```
static readonly VertexDeclaration MyVertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(new VertexElement[]
{
    new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0 ),
    new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0 ),
    new VertexElement(24, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0 ),
    new VertexElement(32, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Tangent, 0 ),
    new VertexElement(44, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Binormal, 0 )
});
```

[image]

I followed the offset and order for these variables in the vertex declaration struct and it seems to be working. How do I make mmp.VertexBuffer.GetData() also gather the Color from the model, Thankyou.

Comment: Single vs instancing: What if you change the float4x4 instanceTransform to row_major float4x4 instanceTransform?

Comment: Hello Jeroen thankyou for your comment, when I used row_major it had the same result as just using float4x4 instance = transpose(instanceTransform); by itself.

with both row_major and transpose it loses its world position it looks like all the instancing starts at position 0,0,0 and stretch's over the whole map.

Comment: Just another suggestion, what about alignment of the fields in the struct (multiply of 16bytes)  (it might only apply to constantbuffers?)  (too long ago sorry)